# how to change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in binary(Python)

Tags: python, binary, complement

all.

I want to change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in binary.

for example,

if binary is 00000110.
I want to change it to 11111001.

how to do that in python3?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ~ operator. If A = 00100, ~A = 11011.
If A is a string version of a decimal, convert it into int first.